# how to check the number of columns in the pipe separator and the contents of the pipe separator in a certain column

Tags: karate

i have data whose output is data with pipe separator ( | ), what is the syntax to check the return of | (pipe separator) has many " x " columns, and the " y " column contains responseMessage.

can validate:

1. Check the reverse for xx columns
2. column y contains yyyy

Comment: again, I ask you to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - hint - provide an example, and it will be much easier for others to help you

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming each row represents one data row of data.  A new line would separate rows.  Given this, I think you are reading each line and then processing it.  The logic would be that if you have N pipes, you would have N+1 columns.  I.e., If you have three pipes '|', you would have four columns.

```
data|data|data|data
data|data|data|data
data|data|data|data
```

I believe this is what you were trying to figure out.